# For any $\varepsilon>0$ there is measurable set $E$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$ such that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$ on $E$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $1 \leq p<\infty$ and $f \in L_\mu^p(X)$. Assume $\mu(X)=\infty$ and $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure. Prove that:

(a) For any $\varepsilon>0$ there is measurable set $E$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$ such that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$ on $E$.

(b) If $s$ is a simple function then $s \in L_\mu^p(X)$ iff there is measurable set $E$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$ such that $s(x)=0$ for $x \notin E$.

I don't seem to have much to work with, I would like to let $E=\{x:|f(x)|<\varepsilon\}$, which would be measurable since $f \in L_\mu^p(X)$, but I don't know how to prove its measure is finite.

Comment: You should check your proof strategy on an easy case, e.g. $(x\mapsto x^{-2})$ on $L^1((1,\infty))$. $E$ is never of finite measure in that case... you need to find a different kind of $E$, or perhaps prove that it would be a fallacy if no such $E$ existed

Comment: (a) For any $\varepsilon>0$,  $E_\varepsilon:=\{|f|<\varepsilon\}\neq\emptyset$ other wise $X=\{|f|\geq\varepsilon\}$ and so $\int|f|^p\,d\mu\geq\varepsilon\mu(X)=\infty$.  The conclusion follows from $\sigma$-finitemess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a), let
$$
X = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty X_n.
$$
We may assume that $X_i \cap X_j = \emptyset$ if $i \neq j$.

Let $G_n = \{x \in X_n : \vert f(x) \vert < \epsilon\}$. (Hence every $G_n$ is a measurable set.) If $\mu(G_n) = 0$ for all $n$ then
$$
\int_X \vert f\vert^p d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{X_n} \vert f \vert^p d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{X_n \smallsetminus G_n} \vert f \vert^p d\mu \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{X_n \smallsetminus G_n} \epsilon^p d\mu = \epsilon^p \mu(X) = \infty,
$$
a contradiction. Let $E = G_n$ for (say the smallest) $n$ such that $\mu(G_n) > 0$. The conclusion is that there exists a measurable set $E$ with $0 < \mu(E) < \infty$ such that $\vert f(x) \vert < \epsilon$ on $E$.